# AngularJS: ng-repeat track by $index inside nested loops

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need a second $index for my nested ng-repeat loop. How and where should I put it?

[AngularJS site](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) says

> Creating aliases for these properties is possible with ngInit. This
>   may be useful when, for instance, nesting ngRepeats.

```
<div ng-repeat="person in persons track by $index">
    <div ng-repeat="something in array track by $index2"> <!-- where to init this and how to manage it?-->
```

If I use $index again, it seems to work but I am not sure this is the right thing?
I am sure there is an easy and correct way of doing it, I just wasn't able to find an example.

Thanks

Answer (score 151, accepted):

`$index` will refer to the index on the innermost `ngRepeat` scope, so if that's what you need, you can just use it.

What the docs is describing is a scenario where you need access to `$index` in the parent `ngRepeat`. You can get it in a couple of ways: One is to use `$parent`, and another is to use `ngInit`, as the Angular docs suggested. Here's an example...

```
<li ng-repeat="thing in things" ng-init="parentIndex = $index">
    {{ $index }}
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="value in thing.values">
            {{ value }} 
            {{ $index }} <!-- inner $index -->
            {{ $parent.$index }} <!-- parent $index -->
            {{ parentIndex }} <!-- also parent $index -->
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvhp9tff/)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know. Was a bit confused with the docs. Thank you

Comment: Worth noting is that it works for any javascript object available. I used it to create an alias for the outer loops $last boolean to make it available in the inner loop.

Comment: By very very very careful with this approach if you intend to delete any list items later on from the array. For example, if you delete any array items from the array `things`, then $index will update itself to reflect the new state of the array, but `parentIndex` will still point to the index of the deleted item. This will be huge problem when it comes to deletion. The `parentIndex` will reflect correctly once you have saved the state & refreshed the page i.e. you have to re-render the array list in order to show updated indices. I figured this after struggling with it for 3 days.

Comment: I have a complicated structure where in i am creating Forms using nested For Loops. For me 'ng-init' solved this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for this. Can't believe I will get hired and work on AngularJS this year 2022 but yeah this saved my nested repeat custom directive. Thanks again

Comment: Cannot stress enough the importance of @Devner warning regarding using this approach if you are deleting objects from an array based on the index. It will not work. I struggled with the same issue