# Combining ng repeat and django template language

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

I have a table that will have varying columns over time and I want my django view to support those changing columns.  I also want to use ng-repeat to do some fancy stuff with it such as filtering and other things.  However I am having trouble combining the two.

I am passing in the arbitrary `col_names` with django template language.  `packages` is also sent in with the django template language and is essentially a json array where each row is a `dict` mapping `col_name` to some value.  i.e.

```
$scope.packages = [{'col1': 'row1col1', 'col2': 'row2val2'}, {'col1': 'row2col1' ....
```

However when I go to put in the rows using `packages` I can't "nest" my templates.  Is there a way to grab arbitrary values out of each row in `packages?

```
<input ng-model="search" placeholder="Search">
        <table style="width:100%;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Permanent Column 1</th>
                    <th>Permanent Column 2</th>
                    {# changing columns #}
                    {% for col_name in col_names %}
                        <th>{{ col_name }}</th>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="package in packages | filter:searchPackage">
                    {% for col_name in columns %}
                        <td>{{package.{{ col_name }}}}</td>  DOESN'T WORK!
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

In that problem line I essentially want to have `{{package.ACTUAL_ARBITRARY_COL_NAME}}` but I don't know how to do that programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem

By default, Django and AngularJS use the same tokens `{{` and `}}` for templating.

So this gets first processed by Django template

```
{% for col_name in columns %}
    <td>{{package.{{ col_name }}}}</td>  DOESN'T WORK!
        ^                        ^
        |________________________| 
         Django template will try to process this value
```

Because Django tries to expand what's inside the first `{{...}}`, you will not get what you want AngularJS to see.

[If you want to continue down that road, I suggest you read some solutions to this problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302928/angularjs-with-django-conflicting-template-tags)

### Better solution

A better approach is to give AngularJS the items you want Django to loop for you.

```
$scope.columns = [...];
```

[Then use AngularJS to do all the loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742361/angularjs-ng-repeat-track-by-index-inside-nested-loops). Whichever way you do it, if you need it done in AngularJS, better do it all in AngularJS and not half-Django half-AngularJS.

Comment: totally agree with last statement ... django should be considered as simply a data API. Mixing templating engines is far more trouble than it's worth